# Open navigation drawer from right to left with ModalDrawer in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-compose

I have been trying to implement navigation drawer in Jetpack compose. The following code shows a simple way to do it:

```
@Composable
fun ModalDrawerSample() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            Column {
                Text("Text in Drawer")
                Button(onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.close()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Close Drawer")
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            Column {
                Text("Text in Bodycontext")
                Button(onClick = {

                    scope.launch {
                        drawerState.open()
                    }

                }) {
                    Text("Click to open")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

But how do I make navigation drawer open from right to left?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [**`LocalLayoutDirection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalLayoutDirection()) providing a `LayoutDirection.Rtl` value.

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {
    ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = { /* ...*/ },
        content = { /* ..*/ }
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: doing that caused my layout to get inverted right to left, too.

Comment: Solved it by additionally using  "CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr)" inside content parameter.

Comment: How to implement two drawer from left and right

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Thanks a lot. You saved my day :) Is there may a more idiomatic way of doing this in 2022?

Comment: Based on this reply, I made a crude copy of the Scaffold function specifically to allow the drawer to come in from the right (assumes default LTR layout with a requirement to have the drawer come in from the right) --> https://gist.github.com/doc2dev/a308d580984df6529132388e153762de

Comment: I combined Gabriele and Sparsh's posts and found that I needed to wrap the drawerContent with a Column first, since the Rtl was applied to the Column that is used under the hood.  I created a gist with what I have so far, including a screenshot: https://gist.github.com/free2bcreative/7c9befbeaf0b6155b3b83d43af968b01

Comment: This is rather a hack than an actual solution.