# How to flip JetPack Compose SideMenu in Scaffold to drag from Right to Left?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was wondering If there's a simple way to change the side menu drag direction to be from right to left in Scaffold;

My Code

```
val state = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = state,
        topBar = {
           ToolBar(state, scope, currentDestination, navController, mainViewModel)
            }
        },
        drawerContent = {
           SideMenu(navController, state, scope, mainViewModel)
        },
        drawerElevation = 4.dp,
        drawerGesturesEnabled = hasSideMenu,
        bottomBar = {
          BottomNavigator(navController, mainViewModel)
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Navigation(
            navController = navController,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
            mainViewModel
        )
    }
```

followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690983/open-navigation-drawer-from-right-to-left-with-modaldrawer-in-jetpack-compose), I had to wrap the whole scaffold in the LocalLayoutDirection.RTL then wrap BottomNavigation, TopBar and Scaffold content in LocalLayoutDirection.LTR to reverse the parent
LocalLayoutDirection.RTL effect on them!

There must be a simpler solution related to Scaffold usage?

Answer (score 1):

As of now the Scaffold does not give us simpler option to change this.

Like you said we can use `LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl` in order to change Scaffold's layout drawing direction from right to left.

This will make all children like top bar, content etc to be drawn from right to left, to fix that we need to wrap all children in `LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr`

Snippet:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ScaffoldDemo() {
    val materialBlue700 = Color(0xFF1976D2)
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Open))
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
        Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            topBar = {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
                    TopAppBar(title = { Text("TopAppBar") }, backgroundColor = materialBlue700)
                }
            },
            floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
            floatingActionButton = {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
                    FloatingActionButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Text("X")
                    }
                }

            },
            drawerContent = {
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
                    Text(text = "drawerContent", color = Color.Black, fontSize = 55.sp)
                }
            },
            content = { padd ->
                Text(
                    text = "BodyContent",
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontSize = 55.sp
                )
            },
            bottomBar = { BottomAppBar(backgroundColor = materialBlue700) { Text("BottomAppBar") } })
    }
}
```

Although, as you can see in the preview, this **does not work** if we need to use fab on the right side of screen.

[image: Preview Image]